# detached entity passed to persist for batch insert in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

For the following batch insert method, i get this exception "detached entity passed to persist". Could you take a look at this **method** and give me some hints?

Thank you so much.

if needed, I will provided the entities here, for the moment I provide **Keyword entity** :

```
public class Keyword implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1429681347817644570L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="key_id")
    private long keyId;   

    @Column(name="key_name")
    private String keyName;   

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name="tweet_id")
     private Tweet tweet;


    public long getKeyId() {
        return keyId;
    }


    public void setKeyId(long keyId) {
        this.keyId = keyId;
    }

    public String getKeyName() {
        return keyName;
    }

    public void setKeyName(String keyName) {
        this.keyName = keyName;
    }


    public Tweet getTweet() {
        return tweet;
    }

    public void setTweet(Tweet tweet) {
        this.tweet = tweet;
    }

}
```

Here **Tweet** Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tweets")

public class Tweet implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="tweet_id")
    private long tweetId;

    @Column(name="tweet_text")
    private String tweetText;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name="lang_code")
    private String languageCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tweet")
    //@JoinColumn(name="hashtag_id")
    private List<Hashtag> hashtags;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tweet")
    //@JoinColumn(name="url_id")
    private List<Url> urls;


    public List<Keyword> getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }


    public void setKeywords(List<Keyword> keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tweet")
    //@JoinColumn(name="url_id")
    private List<Keyword> keywords;




    public long getTweetId() {
        return tweetId;
    }


    public void setTweetId(long tweetId) {
        this.tweetId = tweetId;
    }


    public String getTweetText() {
        return tweetText;
    }


    public void setTweetText(String tweetText) {
        this.tweetText = tweetText;
    }


    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }


    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }


    public String getLanguageCode() {
        return languageCode;
    }


    public void setLanguageCode(String languageCode) {
        this.languageCode = languageCode;
    }


    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }


    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    public List<Hashtag> getHashtags() {
        return hashtags;
    }


    public void setHashtags(List<Hashtag> hashtags) {
        this.hashtags = hashtags;
    }


    public List<Url> getUrls() {
        return urls;
    }


    public void setUrls(List<Url> urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (tweetId ^ (tweetId >>> 32));
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Tweet other = (Tweet) obj;
        if (tweetId != other.tweetId)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

And here **Url** entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tweet_url")
public class Url implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="url_id")
    private int urlId;


    @Column(name="url")
    private String url;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tweet_id",referencedColumnName="tweet_id")
    private Tweet tweet;

    public int getUrlId() {
        return urlId;
    }

    public void setUrlId(int urlId) {
        this.urlId = urlId;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Tweet getTweet() {
        return tweet;
    }

    public void setTweet(Tweet tweet) {
        this.tweet = tweet;
    }
```

And here is **hashtag** entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tweet_hashtag")
public class Hashtag implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="hashtag_id")
    private int hashtagId;


    @Column(name="hashtag")
    private String hashtag;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tweet_id",referencedColumnName="tweet_id")
    private Tweet tweet;

    public int getHashtagId() {
        return hashtagId;
    }

    public void setHashtagId(int hashtagId) {
        this.hashtagId = hashtagId;
    }

    public String getHashtag() {
        return hashtag;
    }

    public void setHashtag(String hashtag) {
        this.hashtag = hashtag;
    }

    public Tweet getTweet() {
        return tweet;
    }

    public void setTweet(Tweet tweet) {
        this.tweet = tweet;
    }
```

And the **method** :

```
public  void batchInsert(List<Keyword> results) throws HibernateException {

    // chekeywordck if key exists

    //  try {
    em=RunQuery.emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    for(Keyword result:results)
    {

        try{
        em.persist(result.getTweet().getUser());
        }
        catch(ConstraintViolationException ce)
        {
            System.out.print("duplicated insert catched");

        }

        try{
        em.persist(result.getTweet());
        }
        catch(ConstraintViolationException ce)
        {
        System.out.print("duplicated insert catched");
        }

        if(result.getTweet().getHashtags()!=null)
            for(Hashtag hashtag:result.getTweet().getHashtags())
                   em.persist(hashtag);

        if(result.getTweet().getUrls()!=null)
            for(Url url:result.getTweet().getUrls())
                em.persist(url);

       em.persist(result);

        em.flush();
        em.clear();

      //when I put these two line out of this loop, it still is the same. 
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();


       // } 


}
```

And here is the exception :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: model.twitter.entities.Url
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at model.service.QueryResultService.batchInsert(QueryResultService.java:74)
    at controller.ResultsController.save(ResultsController.java:125)
    at controller.ResultsController.parse(ResultsController.java:89)
    at main.TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamConsumer.java:41)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: model.twitter.entities.Url
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the `Url` class or `Tweet.Urls` mapping. Can you add those classes too?

Comment: Thank you in advance. I really need your answer. added two other entites.

Comment: Could you point where is line number 74

Comment: Can you add @Transient to List<URL> in Tweet and try again

Comment: I did, nothing happend, the same

Comment: Actually the problem is while saving result there must a object to which hibernate is not generated the id. My suggestion is set a break point at line 74 and check out inside result to which object id is not generated, specially for URL list.

Comment: No id is not generated, that could be a problem. How to generat? it is also autogenerated in mysql. for all the pk s the same.

Comment: And while saving hashtag and url how the tweetid is set into that?

Comment: public List<Url> createUrls(URLEntity[] allUrls,Tweet tweet)
 Url url=new Url();
     url.setUrl(urlEntity.getExpandedURL()); 
     
     url.setTweet(tweet);
     urls.add(url);

Comment: Checked with breakpoint?

Comment: what checked? pk(s) are null and they are auto generated in mysql

Comment: url_id is always 0, when i debug it. it holds also for other entities like keyword and hashtag. how to set their pk?

Comment: Rather than attempting to add the entities one-by-one, you will be better off doing just `em.persist(result)` with `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` or `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` set on all `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` relationships.  That will automatically save all entities correctly, starting from the `Keyword` being persisted.  Also, try to use reference types for identifier fields (`Long` and `Integer` instead of `long` and `int`).

Comment: Tnx, i did that, now another   problem                                               Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : model.twitter.entities.Tweet.user -> model.twitter.entities.User

Comment: Seems like you have a `User` that has a `non-null` identifier but hasn't been obtained through the `EntityManager`.  Are you populating some of the entities partly through direct user input, such as, an HTML form?  If yes, that won't work because populating the identifier directly into an object that was not obtained through the `EntityManager` throws the ORM off.  You will need to obtain such objects from the `EntityManager` before associating them with other entities.  That is the intended usage pattern for ORMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: your model defines a one-to-many relationship between Tweet and URL **without any cascading**. When you are passing a Tweet instance for persisting, the URL objects have not yet been saved and your model does not mandate Tweet to cascade the persist operation to the URL instances. Therefore it can not create the relationship with them.
Cascading tells the hibernate, how to execute DB operations on related entities. 
You can instruct it to pass/cascade the persist operation to the related entity, to cascade all operations or an array of operations.

That being said, your problem(1 of them) could be fixed if you modify the relationship with cascading info:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="tweet", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
 private List<Url> urls;
```

But your sample indicates other possible issues and I would encourage you to spent some more time reading Hibernate ORM documentation and practicing on sample model with less relationships.

One of the obvious issues seems to be the lack of understanding of **relationship owner concept**.
For example, in your Tweet-to-Url relationship, URL is the relationship owner(responsible for managing the relationship, e.g. managing the link via foreign key) 
Please consult [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#example.collection.mapping.annotations) or one of hundreds of similar questions [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hibernate%20owner) for more info. 
Depending on how you fill the data, it is possible that you will run into constraint issues, or your entities will not be linked together, because you are not saving the owning side.
Also using try/catch for constraint violations is a very bad way of detecting duplicated entries. ConstraintViolationException can be have many causes and the reason you are getting them is related to the above mentioned relationship mapping issues.
ORM is complex subject and it is really beneficial to start with smaller examples, trying to understand the framework mechanics before moving to the more challenging models. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

For all the persist calls try using this instead:

```
if(result.getTweet().getUser().getId() == null) {
    em.persist(result.getTweet().getUser());
} else {
    result.getTweet().setUser(em.merge(result.getTweet().getUser()));
}

if(result.getTweet().getId() == null) {
    em.persist(result.getTweet());
} else {
    result.setTweet(em.merge(result.getTweet()));
}

if(result.getId() == null) {
    em.persist(result);
} else {
    result = em.merge(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. getId() == null the return of this method is int, how can it be null!?

Comment: getId == 0 ? with this conditions (0 instead 1) it does not insert any url or hashtag. I will think about the code.

Comment: Then switch to Integer or use the unsaved-value.

Comment: Thanks i used Integer and it still does not insert into hashtags or url, How should we insert hashtags or urls? we do not have any cascade in the tweet entity.